# Is it possible to use another blacklist with Qlproxy? (QuintoLabs Content Security)

Tags: proxy, squid, content-filter

Im using the Qlproxy content filter. It use the urlblacklist. But that blacklist is full of false positives! Is there a better black list? How to use it with qlproxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently version 1.4.2 (and probably upcoming 2.0.0) supports only "url black list". But the filtering engine itself does not check that the list indeed comes from urlblacklist.com, so it is possible to trick the engine into using another black list provider.

The only requirement is that the unpacked blacklist was stored in /var/opt/quintolabs/qlproxy/spool/urlblock/blacklists. Subfolders in this folder are considered to be categories and "domains" file in each category should contain blocked domain name line by line. So it is possible to arrange your own categories and include your own domains there (in this case you might need to disable automatic download in /opt/quintolabs/qlproxy/bin/update_urlblock.sh)

This is a manual work however.. the web site states http://www.shallalist.de can also be used as a replacement but I am not sure if it gives more false positives or not.